gpg suddenly won't ask for password, "cancelled by user"
Suddenly, gpg won't ask for password when trying to decrypt file and instead says "cancelled by user".  I have already tried..
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY

with no effect.  I get the following..
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

I back up these files on multiple servers but I'm worried one day I will be bricked out of all of them.  Sometimes they work over ssh and other times they don't.
/dev/pts/0


in light of the comment - Sometimes they work over ssh and other times they don't - it's not clear if the issue is occurring with a 'local' decrypt or a remote/ssh decrypt; the fact some ssh sessions work and others don't seems to imply different settings/configs on the remote hosts(?); cancelled by user sounds like an issue with the (popup) window that prompts for a passphrase

short of listing several possible fixes ... have you tried a web search on gpg "cancelled by user" "decryption failed" "no secret key" GPG_TTY ssh? hits cover a few issues like setting pinentry-program in gpg-agent.conf, chmod o+rw $(tty), etc

Weird question: run ls -l /dev/tty when it's broken.  If it's a symlink I have a similar issue.

@markp-fuso It always works locally.  It is over ssh where it is inconsistent even with the same connection.

I did search and that is where I found the export GPG_TTY method although it didn't work.  I don't quite understand gpg enough to parse this problem.  Like where are the keys?  Why does the password box not pop up on some ssh connections?

GPG seems to go through extra effort to make sure password prompts go to a human being, and sometimes it doesn't accept that a human is on the other end of SSH.

@davolfman That has been my experience.  It is very inconsistent, even on subsequent same client/server connections.

Rebooting the server solved the problem.  I don't know why.  This is a crap answer but it solved my problem and my help someone else.
